# Natural measures of curvature of Riemannian manifold along two-dimensional subspace

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Given a Riemannian manifold $M$, a point $p \in M$, and some two-dimensional subspace $\varSigma$ of $T_{p}M$, the sectional curvature $K(\varSigma)$ is a well-known, natural measure of the curvature of $M$ along $\varSigma$. Given two orthonormal vectors $v,w \in T_{p}M$ spanning $\varSigma$, it may be computed via the curvature endomorphism and the metric $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$, as follows:
$$
K(\varSigma) = \langle R(v,w)w, v\rangle \,.
$$

On the other hand, we may associate to $\varSigma$ a different measure $\tilde{K}(\varSigma)$ of the curvature of $M$ along $\varSigma$, defined by the length squared of the vector $R(v,w)w$:

$$
\tilde{K}(\varSigma) = \langle R(v,w)w, R(v,w)w\rangle \,.
$$

As far I can understand, $K(\varSigma) \neq \tilde{K}(\varSigma)$ in general.

My question is: What is the geometric meaning of $\tilde{K}(\varSigma)$?

EDIT: I overlooked the possibility that $\tilde{K}$ might not be well defined.

Comment: It seems to me that, if well-defined, your measure is the square of the sectional curvature, isn’t it?